# Complex Roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ satisfy the equation $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = 0$ but not $(x+\alpha)(x+\beta) = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I would like to ask a question about Complex Roots in Further Mathematics.

I am new to the subject and one of the statements given in the book without further explanation is

> If the roots of the equation are $\alpha$ and $\beta$, the equation is $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = 0$
>   
> Hence, $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = x^2 - \alpha x - \beta x + \alpha \beta = x^2 - (\alpha + \beta)x + \alpha \beta$

Now, I have a question. 
Why is the equation given as:

$$(x-\alpha)(x-\beta) = 0$$

and not as

$$(x+\alpha)(x+\beta) = 0$$

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: The roots of $(x + \alpha)(x + \beta)$ are $-\alpha$ and $-\beta$. The book isn't quite right as the equation could have the form $c(x - 'alpha)(x-\beta)$ for $c$ any non-zero constant.

Comment: just try to plug in the second eq $x=\alpha$

Comment: This is certainly **not** off topic, unless questions where the OP has a mistaken understanding of elementary algebra are now considered to be off-topic in MSE. I thought MSE existed to help such people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inserting $\alpha$ into $(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$ gives you $(\alpha-\alpha)(\alpha-\beta)$, which you can quickly confirm is equal to $0$. Same with inserting $\beta$.

On the other hand, inserting into $(x+\alpha)(x+\beta)$ doesn't give you zero (except in very special circumstances). So in order to make sure that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are indeed roots, $-$ is the operation of choice.

Answer (score 2):

$x-\alpha$ has the root $\alpha$ while $x+\alpha$ has the root $-\alpha$. Simple as that.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1067430)

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: I disagree with that. The answer being short doesn't mean it is not a relevant answer.

Comment: "Simple as that" is a deeply irritating thing to say in this context: you and I both view the algebra as trivial, but the OP isn't as familiar with algebra as you or I and needs help.

Comment: @RobArthan: I might have added that the question is not restricted to the contexts of quadratic equation but in fact to any binomial and that once you observe that there is no minus in front of $\alpha$ then there must be a minus rather than a plus and blahblah. I disagree with the reviewer: this *is* the answer. It is shorter because it is more general.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: yes, that would have been a useful extension to your answer, leading the OP towards an understanding of polynomial division.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a root is $P(r)=0$. So if $P(x):=(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$, then $P(\alpha)=P(\beta)=0$. On the other hand, if $Q(x):=(x+\alpha)(x+\beta)$, then it's not necessarily true that $Q(\alpha)=0$.